# Ruby Script to Process each line in an SQL file

Tags: mysql, ruby, regex, gsub

I am having a problem with this script that I have written to scour through an .sql file, and replace certain string contents. E.g.

I am trying to replace:

```
result of using this information. If you have any comments, queries or concerns with regards to the above information, 

Please <a href="#" target="_blank">Click Here</a>&nbsp;for different contact options.</p>
<h4>Stone properties:</h4>
<p><span>Scientific name of the stone:</span> Quartz/Silicon dioxide</p>
<p><span>Group:</span> Silicates &ndash; tektosilicates</p>
```

to look like across a 1000 database lines:

```
Please <a href="#" target="_blank">Click Here</a>&nbsp;for different contact options.</p>
<ul class="navlistjdxcms">
<h4>Stone properties:</h4>
<li><span>Scientific name of the stone:</span> Quartz/Silicon dioxide</li>
<li><span>Group:</span> Silicates &ndash; tektosilicates</li>
```

The idea is to match the HTML tags, and then change the tags and add CSS classes without altering the other text/lines in the database file. So far I have come up with this:

```
full_path_to_read = File.expand_path('C:\Users\huber\Desktop\RubyReg\cms_page.sql')
full_path_to_write = File.expand_path('C:\Users\huber\Desktop\RubyReg\cms_page2.sql')

stringla = ""

File.open(full_path_to_read).each_line { |s|

    contents = s
    xyz = contents.scan(/<p><span>.*?<\/span>.*?<\/p>/o)
    new_str = xyz.to_s.gsub('<p>', '<li>')
    new_str2 = new_str.gsub('</p>', '</li>')
    new_string = '<ul class="navlistjdxcms">' + new_str2 + '</ul>'
    m = s.gsub((/<p><span>.*?<\/span>.*?<\/p>/o), "#{new_string}")
    stringla += m
}

File.open(full_path_to_write, "w+") { |f| f.write(stringla) }
```

but seem to be getting the

```
<ul class="navlistjdxcms">
```

being displayed for every match of

```
/<p><span>.*?<\/span>.*?<\/p>/o
```

that there is in the file.

I have tried many Ruby regex expressions and tried connecting directly to the database to alter the database from there, but can't seem to figure it out.

I have also attempted to use:

```
m = s.gsub("#{xyz}", "#{new_string}")
```

and many other variations of this without much success. How would I do it so that it replaces the whole matched paragraph with the new_string not just the single matched line? I also have some feeling that I am doing something else wrong with Ruby strings and classes here.

I know this is Ruby Regex 101, just can't seem to figure it out. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `each_line` so you're only getting one line at a time. Given that, I trust it's clear why you're seeing the results you're seeing.

Since there are only a 1000 sections like this, you can read in the entire file and do a global replace with capture groups to get the result you want.

I couldn't get the regex to work on regexplanet, which supports replacement, but you can see the match groups working at http://rubular.com/r/ahSEerTEnW. After doing the match, you could construct the new replacement text using literals combined with the match group references (\1, \2, \3, \4), as in:

```
\1
<ul class="navlistjdxcms">
\2
<li>\3</li>
<li>\4</li>
```

Comment: I'd love to have some additional info on capture groups. I have done initial research and tried but not been successful.

One question though, does the 'each_line' code iterate over each individual .sql line or over the html '\r\n' within each line in the  file?

Because the problem that I have noticed from the output is that the '"#{new_string}"' replaces every instance of '/<p><span>.*?<\/span>.*?<\/p>/o' on the line and not as the group on that line as a whole? When I try 'm = s.gsub(#{xyz}, "#{new_string}")' to try to fix this it doesnt work?

Comment: It iterates over each line of the file, Rocky. As for the capture groups, I'll start a regex fiddle you can look at.

Comment: See updated answer for reference to regex with capture groups.